# HDFS + different disk size nodes + data volume choosing policy

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, ambari, hdp

Lets say we have the following cluster with the following details

10 node HDFS cluster, and 4 are of disk size - 10 TB and 6 node of disk size - 1TB

On Hadoop - 2.6, cloudera - 5.8 , we have ability to change the default from round robin to available space in case the disks on data node machine are with different size

Example

look at dfs.datanode.fsdataset.volume.choosing.policy. By default this is set to round-robin but since you have an asymmetric disk setup you should change it to available space.

[image]

Since we have hortonwoks HDP cluster version 2.6.5 ,

we are searching the same ability

So we search in ambari  HDFS --> config
But we not found the configuration about `round-robin  / available space.`

Dose `HDP 2.6.5 ambari` cluster can give this ability ?

The goal is to balance the data on all disks consider that some disks are small then others

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with any such balancing rules or properties, but you can apply node labels in Ambari configs such that your datanodes will be loaded with different configs (such as the mount points of the datanodes)

The only way I've done rebalancing is by the HDFS rebalance CLI

You could also try putting that `dfs.datanode.fsdataset.volume.choosing.policy` property into the custom hdfs-site.xml section, however Round Robin is the default and the available space one is not recommended, based on the Cloudera forums I've found

If you want to set it to the available space property anyway, it's 
`org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.fsdataset.AvailableSpaceVolumeChoosingPolicy`

Comment: you said - The only way I've done rebalancing is by the HDFS re balance CLI , do you have example ?

Comment: https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.7.2/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-hdfs/HDFSCommands.html#balancer

Comment: about - org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.fsdataset.AvailableSpaceVolumeChoosingPolicy , how to set this in HDFS --> CONFIG ?

Comment: from what I see , this - org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.fsdataset.AvailableSpaceVolumeChoosingPolicy is relevant only for cloudera not hostronworks cluster see - https://idwcm.sita.aero/static/help/topics/admin_dn_storage_balancing.html

Comment: It's a global Hadoop property, Cloudera/Hortonworks wouldn't "remove" it, only one may "choose to expose it". You can find it on the Apache site https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.7.6/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-hdfs/hdfs-default.xml

Comment: ok but not understand if HDP ambari cluster also support this feature ?

Comment: Yes... It's still the same Apache Hadoop.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205688/discussion-between-king-david-and-cricket-007).